# Regular expression for multiple email destinations delimited by semicolon

Tags: c#, regex

I succeed to do regular expression for single email like this:

```
private readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                                          + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
```

Now, I need to make regular expression for more than one email, and delimited by semicolon

```
test@gmail.com;test2@yahoo.com;test3@gmail.com
```

I found this regular expression:

```
\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([,;]\s*\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*
```

but the problem that this regular expression also "receive" this string:

```
h@kj.com;asds@gmail
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's not build a regular expression for more than one because this one is complex enough, just validate them individually:

```
foreach (var email in emailList.Split(new char[] { ';' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    // validate email
}
```

further, regular expressions aren't all that well suited for something like this because the user could have put a space, more than one space, before or after the semicolon - it just gets messy - and emails are messy enough already.